# 2-Pole 40 amp GFCI replacement for electric range tripping

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci, replacement, range

I am located in MA.

1. Do I need to have a GFCI for an electric 4 wire range?
2. When I replaced the current 2-pole 40 amp circuit breaker with a 2-Pole 40 amp GFCI replacement for electric range the circuit trips and does not turn on. I have confirmed that it's wired correctly and have not been able to figure out why it's tripping. The ground and neutral are connected properly.
   The range is 4 wire.

This one is resolved!
Had to cut the "jumper" between ground and neutral.
[image: Had to cut the "jumper" between ground and neutral.]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you clarify that second item; is it another question? And where are you located? (Please edit the info into your question.) And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Is your range within 6' of your sink?  Is your range receptacle a 3-wire or a 4-wire receptacle?

Comment: 2020 NEC changed requirements, your local authority may not have adopted the current version or the change in 210.8.  Do you know what edition has been adopted?

Comment: You say it’s connected properly. Just to make sure, the white wire to the range is connected to the neutral terminal on the breaker, not the neutral bus on the panel?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease The code you mentioned, pasted below, does not apply to ranges:
2020 Code Language:https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=808.0

Comment: @DoxyLover correct, the white wire goes into the breaker and the white pig tail goes to the bus on the panel.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the receptacle is a 4 wire and more than 6 feet away from the sink. But everything I found says that the 6 feet code does not apply to the range. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: @VadimK  It does apply to ranges in the locations specified. Where had you provided information to indicate it didn't apply? You hadn't specified location, and location wouldn't be required if you had specified information indicating enforceable code. https://www.nema.org/docs/default-source/technical-document-library/nec-adoption-map.pdf

Comment: Is the kitchen in a home (dwelling unit), business, or some other type of occupancy?

Comment: If the home was built prior to the adoption of the 2020 code adoption in the US 240v devices did not require GFCI protection unless required by a local jurisdiction. see my answer for the code reference .

Comment: @EdBeal I remodeled a condo unit built in 1986.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the wiring on the connection block on the back of the range. Make sure that the neutral and the ground are not connected. If the neutral and ground are connected, the GFCI will trip.

The neutral and ground are not supposed to be connected on the connection block with a four wire cord and ground going all the way to the panel. Some installers aren't properly trained and will leave the neutral and ground connected on the back of the range.

Comment: That sounds dangerous. Could you please explain why?

Comment: Connecting the case ground to the neutral is dangerous, but as has been pointed out numerous times on this site this is the connection method specified in installation instructions for three wire plugs for dryer or range, i.e., plugs with hot1, hot2, neutral. If a four wire cord were connected that way, the appliance would work properly with a standard breaker, and the user would be unaware. The problem is that there would be current in the ground wire in normal operation, but the ground is only supposed to carry current in case of a fault.

Comment: Ok, so with a 4 wire you are saying completely disconnecting the neutral and ground wires at the oven base is safe? I’m new and just want to make sure I fully understand and that it’s actually safe.

Comment: The neutral of the cord MUST be connected to the neutral on the connection block. The ground of the cord MUST be connected to the ground on the case. BUT there is a neutral to ground "jumper" on the connection block which is NOT to be connected to the ground in a four wire connection.

Comment: So sounds like there are 5 wires on the range connection block. Is that correct?

Comment: One range I was supervising the delivery of for a relative had this jumper as a flat metal strip that was supposed to be removed or cut for a four wire cord. The installers would not do it and I had to do it.

Comment: If you have instructions it will explain how to set up a four wire connection. It can be confusing. Some appliances come with the jumper in place for a 3 wire cord and it must be moved for a 4 wire cord. Could you take a pic of your connection block and attach to your post?

Comment: Will do as soon as I can. Might be tomorrow. I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Jm, thanks so much. This worked. I cut the jumper and I was able to turn the breaker on and test.

Answer (score 1):

### You do not need a GFCI for the range, even under the 2020 NEC

While the 2020 NEC expanded the *types of receptacles* that require GFCI protection, it did *not* expand dwelling unit kitchen GFCI *location* requirements beyond receptacles serving countertops and receptacles near sinks, so since a range receptacle does not serve a countertop (it's behind the range), it does not fall under 210.8(A)(6).  This leaves 210.8(A)(7), which covers receptacles within six feet of a sink, and that does not apply to your situation either, as you have indicated.

As to why the GFCI was tripping? "Calrod" type heating elements can generate leakage currents at startup due to small amounts of moisture contaminating the internal (powdered ceramic) insulation, and it was likely this leakage that tripped the GFCI.  Of course, that assumes a correctly wired range -- leaving the bonding jumper in when doing a 3-wire to 4-wire switchover will also trip a GFCI straight away, as you observed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  I the circuit trips as soon as I turn it on. Any idea on how to resolve this? One guy suggested disconnecting the ground and neutral at the base of the range (ikea).

Comment: I interpret this suggestion to mean disconnecting the jumper which connects the neutral to the case ground screw on the stove. You cannot disconnect the neutral of the cord from the neutral screw on the connection block. DO NOT DO THIS.

Answer (score 0):

Two long for a comment:
In the past 240v did not require a GFCI only 120v did ,,,

in fact the old code books pre 2020 for several cycles showed a counter top where 120v GFCI’s were required a standard 240v non GFCI protected circuit was adjacent to the 120v circuit, (2014 & 2017 NEC exhibit 210.16 120v receptacle within 6’ of a sink, 240v at same location NOT protected)

The 240v requirement is newer, since you didn’t have a GFCI originally I would put the old breaker back. Just because code requires them now doesn’t mean you have to upgrade.

I tell folks that have me do this once they are in if required by current code I can not remove them. Why ? Because if a remodel required them they would be required.
A remodel is much more than redecorating many people don’t understand this changing wall coverings, flooring cabinets and even receptacles is redecorating and most states do not require any type of permits or inspections as this is more of a maintenance thing (there are a few that require even a receptacle change to be done by a licensed electrician but most allow the home owner to do their own electrical work.)

True remodeling moving windows and walls usually requires permits and inspections, this is the requirement for the states I have done what most call “remodeling” the code even allowed 3 wire ranges to stay.

Is it a good idea to update to GFCI ? Possibly but as you found out not always. Older devices themselves can be the issue. Older refrigerators commonly trip GFCI’s and code did not start requiring 240v GFCI’s until the last code cycle.